A movie about turning 51
I'm trying to remember the name of a movie.
I'm reasonably sure that it was American, and probably made in the 80s or early 90s.
The main character was a man turning 51 (I think, possibly 41?).
The main point was that turning 50 was OK; but turning 51 was the point that you realized that you were in your 50s. This lead to the character having a mid life crisis.
I could be getting mixed up; but I want to say that the character decides he wants to move away somewhere like Alaska.
Apologies for the lack of detail - I think it must be around twenty years since I saw it.
The lead character was a man. I can't really remember if he was married. I think that it was a dramedy. In my head, the lead actor was someone like John Goodman, but that might be a massive red herring. I think that in the end he does end up leaving his life / troubles behind and moving away 

was the main character a man or a woman? Do you have any other detail of the plot? Was he/she married? Comedy / horror / drama?

Sorry for the very vague description.
The lead character was a man. I can't really remember if he was married.
I think that it was a dramedy.
In my head, the lead actor was someone like John Goodman, but that might be a massive red herring.
I think that in the end he does end up leaving his life / troubles behind and moving away

I think you confused Goodman with "Norm!". This is very likely the 1994 comedy Hostage For A Day.

The film centers around a Warren Kooey (played by George Wendt), a copy-shop worker who [upon turning] 41, begins having a mid-life crisis. His plans are to take a trip to the state of Alaska, but his plans are derailed after his wife drains his entire bank account (approximately $40,000) to pay for a remodeling job by famous homebuilder and blond, long-haired Italian heartthrob "Hondo." In order to recuperate his money Kooey decides to pose as being held hostage by an imaginary Russian terrorist, and calls the SWAT team on himself in an effort to extort $50,000 (to Kooey's disappointment, the incompetent SWAT team has suffered major budget cuts). Things take a turn for the worse when a real Russian terrorist (Candy) takes Kooey hostage.

It's the only film directed by comedian John Candy (who  also stars in a minor role). Here's the trailer:




Thanks very much! Well done considering my poor description.
